# Implicitly differentiate an equation, then solve the resulting equation

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

Suppose I have an extremely tedious equation to differentiate, and I want *Mathematica* to help do the differentiation and solve.

Consider a less tedious equation:

$$y (x,z)  = \sin \left(\frac{1}{x} \right) - \frac{1}{x} - z $$

Can *Mathematica* find $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} $ at $x=0.3$ by performing implicit differentiation on both sides and solving for $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} $?

Now suppose we try implicit differentiation:

$$ \sin (y) + y = \sin \left(\frac{1}{x} \right)  + xz$$

I want to find $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}  $ at $x=0.3$, $y=0.4$ and $z=0.5$. It should give a value of $5.94$.

Tried this, but didn't work:

```
sin [y] + y == sin [1/x] + x z
D[y[x_, y_, z_], x] /. {x -> 0.3,  y -> 0.2, z -> 0.5}
```

Comment: what is z? constant? function of x?

Comment: z is just another variable, oops it should be y(x,z)

Comment: So you'd like mma to differentiate, obtaining $\partial_x y=f(x,z)$, then set $x=3$ and obtain some function of $z$ for the rhs and then what? What's the next step?

Comment: Note: In *Mathematica*, `Sin[y]`, not `sin[y]` and so forth.

Comment: You could use the formula $\partial y/\partial x = - (\partial f/\partial x) / (\partial f/\partial y)$, if the equation is put in the form $f(x,y,z)=0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I often do this sort of thing with [`Dt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dt.html).  It works on equations, too.  It basically gives you the multivariate differential
$$ {\partial f \over \partial x} \;dx + {\partial f \over \partial y} \;dy + \cdots = 0$$
To get $dy/dx$, set $dx = 1$ and any other differential other than $dy$ equal to zero.  Then solve for $dy$ to get $dy = - ({\partial f /\partial x})/({\partial f / \partial y})$, which equals $dy/dx$, since we set $dx = 1$.

In *Mathematica* on the OP's example we get first:

```
Dt[Sin[y] + y == Sin[1/x] + x z]
(* Dt[y] + Cos[y] Dt[y] == z Dt[x] - (Cos[1/x] Dt[x])/x^2 + x Dt[z] *)
```

Now set the differentials to their appropriate values:

```
Dt[Sin[y] + y == Sin[1/x] + x z] /. {Dt[x] -> 1, Dt[z] -> 0}
(* Dt[y] + Cos[y] Dt[y] == z - Cos[1/x]/x^2 *)
```

Then solve for `Dt[y]`:

```
dy = Dt[y] /. First@Solve[
    Dt[Sin[y] + y == Sin[1/x] + x z] /. {Dt[x] -> 1, Dt[z] -> 0},
    Dt[y]
    ]
(* (x^3 + x^2 z - Cos[1/x])/(x^2 (1 + Cos[y])) *)
```

To evaluate numerically, replace the variables with their values:

```
dy /. {x -> 0.3, y -> 0.2, z -> 0.5}
(* 5.91267 *)
```

---

Here's a function to carry out the procedure above for the derivative of an arbitrary variable `y` with respect to a variable `x` from an implicit function defined by an equation `eqn`:

```
d[eqn_Equal, y_Symbol, x_Symbol] := Dt[y] /. First@Solve[
    Dt[eqn] /. {Dt[x] -> 1, HoldPattern@Dt[Except[y]] -> 0},
    Dt[y]
    ]
```

Examples:

```
d[Sin[y] + y == Sin[1/x] + x z, y, x]
(* (x^2 z - Cos[1/x])/(x^2 (1 + Cos[y])) *)

d[Sin[y] + y == Sin[1/x] + x z, y, x] /. {x -> 0.3, y -> 0.2, z -> 0.5}
(* 5.76116 *)

d[2 x + 3 y + 5 z + 7 w == 0, x, w]
(* -(7/2) *)
```

Comment: The answer should be 5.76.The first part is fine. But When I'm using d[Sin[y] + y == Sin[1/x] + x z, y, x] /. {x -> 0.3, y -> 0.2, z -> 0.5} there is an error of "d[False, 0.2, 0.3]

Comment: The `False` indicates that the variables in `Sin[y] + y == Sin[1/x] + x z` had values and the equation evaluated to `False`; in fact, the `0.2, 0.3` indicate what they are for `y` and `x`.  You could try executing `Clear[x, y, z]` first.  Alternatively one could write a fancier function `d` that was `HoldAll` and `Block`-ed the variables.  (That seemed like overkill to me at the time.)

Comment: @user44840 Or perhaps you didn't execute the definition of `d`.

Comment: Perhaps slightly cleaner is `d[eqn_Equal, y_Symbol, x_Symbol] := Dt[y] /. First @ Solve[Dt[eqn], Dt[y]] /. {Dt[x]->1, _Dt->0}`

Answer (score 2):

```
y[x_, z_] := Sin[1/x] - 1/x - z

D[y[x, z], x] /. x -> 0.3
```

Not exactly sure what you wanted to do after that.

**Update 1**

```
y[x_, z_] := Sin[1/x] - 1/x - x z

D[y[x, z], x] /. {x -> 0.3, z -> 1}
```

**Update 2**

```
eqn = Sin[y[x, z]] + y[x, z] == Sin[1/x] + x z

Solve[
  D[eqn, x] /. {x -> 0.3, z -> 0.5, y[x, z] -> 0.4},
  D[y[x, z], x] /. {x -> 0.3, z -> 0.5}
]
```

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean? The second line calculates $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ at $x = 0.3$?

Comment: I ran the code in mathematica, doesn't work..

Comment: @user44840 it's probably useful to explain what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: I get error messages like:

General::ivar: 5 is not a valid variable.

General::ivar: 0.3` is not a valid variable.

Comment: It sounds like you set the variables with some values already. Try and run the following command before the 2 lines above.

    Clear["Global`*"]

Comment: What about implicit differentiation? I've added a new equation above in my post

Comment: Very neat solution, thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

It maybe done by finding first the total derivative of a function f(x,y,z)

```
f = Sin[y] + y - Sin[1/x] - x z;
Dt[f]

(*-z Dt[x] + (Cos[1/x] Dt[x])/x^2 + Dt[y] + Cos[y] Dt[y] - x Dt[z]*)
```

then solve fro both `Dt[y]` and `Dt[x]`

```
dy = Dt[y] /. Solve[Dt[f] == 0, Dt[y]][[1]];
dx = Dt[x] /. Solve[Dt[f] == 0, Dt[x]][[1]];

f2=dy/dx/. {x -> 3/10, y -> 4/10};
f2/.z->0.5

(*-5.93812*)
```

Comment: Funny, this gives `Indeterminate` for `f = x + y` and `1` for `f = x + y + z`, both of which are incorrect.